# SwiftUI app crash on run in macOS environment

Tags: swiftui

I run SwiftUI with following code in iPhone simulator and it's working well, but when run in macOS, it crash the app. I am using Xcode 11 beta 3

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $selection)  {

            Text("Hello world").tabItemLabel(Text("Hello")).tag(0)
            Text("Foo bar").tabItemLabel(Text("Foo")).tag(1)
        }
    }

}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

And I got the following error:

I got the following error COMPATIBILITY BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Moving method contentMinSize from UICanvas to UIWindowScene

Comment: I got the following error

COMPATIBILITY BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Moving method contentMinSize from UICanvas to UIWindowScene

Comment: You probably need to provide more information in your question - what version of Xcode Beta you're using, any code that people could use to potentially recreate the problem, what the specific error message is and where it's appearing, etc. If you edit your question with that information, it would greatly improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the less information. I updated details in question

Comment: Yes may be thanks for the link.